# Run kpartx on system start

Tags: 22.04, startup, udev, dmraid

I'm trying to detect and run partitions on top of jMicron fakeRAID, which is discovered by dmraid. How far I'm stuck with making this automatically during boot.

```bash
hopungo@hopungo-pc:~$ sudo kpartx -l /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 
jmicron_GRAID1 : 0 7813722112 /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 2048
```

Here is a [good known solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65746/automatically-run-kpartx-during-boot) from year 2010, but it is outdated in 2023 (probably, after 22.04). You simply will not find `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-kpartx.rules`. And if you make your own, it doesn't work.

I also tried `mdadm`, with the same result: I need a working way to run it on system start.

Another option is to use `rc.local` script, but it doesn't work too and also looks  a bit crutchy. Is there any canonical way to run `kpartx` on start since 22.04?

Comment: `root`'s `crontab` (`/etc/crontab` - special format, read `man -a crontab`) supports a `@reload` date specification that will execute very late in startup.

Comment: You can create this udev rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a systemd service file, for example:

/usr/lib/systemd/system/custom-jmicron.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Detects and activates partions on jMicron fakeRAID
After=systemd-fsck-root.service
Before=local-fs-pre.target local-fs.target shutdown.target
Wants=local-fs-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=kpartx -a /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

once the file is created, run

```
systemctl enable custom-jmicron.service
```

On the next reboot, that service should run, executing the command kpartx -a /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID once as the service is of type oneshot.

You may need to tweak the After and Before sections to get the timing 100% right, but it should be close.

Comment: Seems to be good solution. I'll check and if everything is OK, accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@reboot** option in your **crontab**, it works fine on most of the distros.

```
@reboot /path/to/your/script.sh
```